# The relationship between ridge regularization and CNN Data Augmentation

Tags: conv-neural-network, regularization, ridge-regression

In Chapter 10.3.4 of *Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in Python* by James et al. there is a sentence on data augmentation for CNNs (adding natural transformations of images into the training set to improve generalization) which says:

> This kind of fattening of the data is similar in spirit to ridge regularization

I have read this thread: [Why is data augmentation classified as a type of regularization?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/295383/why-is-data-augmentation-classified-as-a-type-of-regularization) and understand from the top answer there how data augmentation could be considered a form of regularization.

What I don't understand is the quoted sentence's mention to ridge regularization specifically. I feel that I am missing some much deeper conceptual point on why ridge specifically as opposed to lasso or any other regularization approach in is similar to data augmentation.

The best I can imagine is that with ridge you are effectively smoothing the model coefficients. But fattening the data? I don't see it. Am I just overthinking this? Do they just mean regularization in general?